# Scipy special.chdtr error

Tags: python, scipy, runtime-error

I am performing an iterative process on a vector.

I have done this for many many datasets (which are actually images). And have never encountered an error. On this totally random image I get the following error after many successful iterations:

```
wt = 1-stats.chi2.cdf(chisqr,[bands])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 1347, in cdf
place(output,cond,self._cdf(*goodargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 2540, in _cdf
return special.chdtr(df, x)
TypeError: ufunc 'chdtr' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
could not be   safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting 
rule ''safe''
[Finished in 2640.6s with exit code 1]
```

chdtr(v, x) Returns the area under the left hand tail (from 0 to x) of the Chi square probability density function with v degrees of freedom. I'm not sure what it could have encountered to get this? anyone have a clue? especially because it runs smoothly for many iterations. Anyone have an idea on what could provoke this error?

Comment: What is the dtype of `chisqr`? is it `object`? If so, try changing that to `float`: `chisqr = chisqr.astype('float')` before calling `chi2.cdf`.

Comment: I do get this: type = np.dtype(chisqr)
TypeError: data type not understood         Could that be the problem? how do I change it to float?

Comment: To find the dtype of `chisqr` (assuming it is a NumPy array), print `chisqr.dtype`. Note that it is not clear yet that it is a NumPy array; it might just be a Python list....

Comment: What is `bands`?  I can reproduce your error with, for example, `chi2.cdf(8, [[1],[2,3]])` (i.e. the second argument is not "array-like").

Comment: The error also occurs if `bands` is complex, e.g. `chi2.cdf(8, [1+1j])`.